# Get text between quotation marks

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a text like this `"my text" "my text2"`.
How can I extract `my text` and `my text2` into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your input with:

```
"([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"
```

and capture first group.

This construct will handle embedded quotes as well as empty strings. If you do not want empty strings, replace the first `*` with a `+`.

With PHP, this is done using `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]*(?:\\"[^"]*)*)"/', "input here", $matches);
# use the $matches array
```

Comment: I want it as an array which I can parese with foreach.

Comment: See edit, but you could have found out by yourself ;) It took me 30 seconds of google search and I don't know PHP ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your strings don't have embedded quotes, you could simply use `"(.*?)"`. If they do, then it depends on how you quote them, but `"(([^"\\]|\\.)*)"` would handle backslash-quoted strings such as `"\"\\"`. (Note: None of these strings are themselves quoted, except for the backslashes in the second regexp.)